# Web Audio API Unable to decode audio data

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

Got following error while trying to load mp3 audio file in Google Chrome: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data`. Here's my code:

```
        loadSong(url) {
            var AudioCtx = new AudioContext();

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open('GET', url, true);
            request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
            request.onload = function () {
                console.log(request.response);
                AudioCtx.decodeAudioData(
                    request.response,
                    function (buffer) {
                        var currentSong = AudioCtx.createBufferSource();

                        currentSong.buffer = buffer;
                        currentSong.connect(AudioCtx.destination);
                        currentSong.start(0);
                    },
                    function (e) {
                        alert("error: " + e.err);
                    }
                );
            };
            request.send();
        }
```

Here's console.log of `request.response`:

```
ArrayBuffer(153) {}
byteLength:0
__proto__:ArrayBuffer
byteLength:0
constructor:ƒ ArrayBuffer()
slice:ƒ slice()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag):"ArrayBuffer"
get byteLength:ƒ byteLength()
__proto__:Object
```

In Firefox I got error `The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown type of content.`. Same error with OGG files

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information.  It would be really helpful if you provided the actual ogg file you're trying to decode.